# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' in Employee

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database

my code for the employer in the models.py for the employer:

```
class Employee(Person):

    """
    Employee details and their rights to portal.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    e_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, unique=True)
    student_permit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    company_permit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    placement_permit = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.e_id + '-' + self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.e_id + '-' + self.name)
```

My code in the employer in the context_py function :

```
def get_emp_info(Employee):        
    blood_groups = blood_group_helper()
    genders = gender_helper()
    info = {
        'ename': Employee.name,
        'dob': Employee.dob,
        'gender': [i for i in genders if Employee.gender in i],
        'phone': Employee.phone,
        'address': Employee.curr_address,
        'emp_id': Employee.e_id,
        'bgroup': [i for i in blood_groups if Employee.blood_group in i],
        'photo': os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_URL, employee.photo.name) if Employee.photo else None,
    }
    return info
```

The error is saying :

> File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\placement\placement\helpers\context_helper.py",
>   line 109, in get_emp_info
>       'ename': Employee.name, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

What is this error ? what is this solution in this error??

Comment: It means `Employee` is `None`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8949265/6013016)

Comment: use class Employee(models.Model) instead of class Employee(Person).

Comment: but it is not working and it shows errors